# Android Views appear different when accessed via a JAR in libs

Tags: java, android, jar

I'm working on a reusable library for Android.  The library will include an Activity that developers can use in their apps.

The plan is to distribute the library as a JAR. Consequently, I'm laying out views at runtime in my Activity onCreate(), as I can't use XML resources.

However, I'm noticing this weird behavior where there are subtle size differences between my Activity in two contexts:

1. I'm running my project, directly launching the Activity (Manifest LAUNCHER definition).
2. I zip my project classes into a JAR, and import that JAR into another Android project (testing what other developers will do).  This wrapping project fires an intent for my Activity.

Why would this be?

What I see is that the imported lib version (2) looks *smaller*.  It's some kind of scaling factor that's being applied to the direct launch case (1) that isn't being applied to the imported lib.

I have tried:

1. making sure all my dimensions are in DiPs
2. converting my DiPs values to scaled View dimensions using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics()` and `TypedValue.applyDimension()`